# Why is $\frac{2n!}{n^2+n}=2(n-1)!$?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm reading a book on combinatorics, and I've been asked to expand and simplify the following:

$$\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{n} (j+1)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}i}$$

Given that:

$$\prod_{j=0}^{n} (j+1)=j!$$

and $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$$

I believe that I should write:

$$\frac{n!}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}=\frac{2n!}{n(n+1)}$$

I've looked at the answers in the back of the book and the answer is:

$$2(n-1)!$$

I presume that:

$$\frac{2n!}{n(n+1)}=2(n-1)!$$

But I have no idea on how he simplified it that way. Can you help me?

Comment: In your second line it should be $(j+1)!$, not $j!$.

Comment: Hold on, shouldn't that be (n+1)! in the line with your second product symbol?

Comment: Arithmetic mistake: $\prod_{j = 0}^n (j+1) = (n + 1)!$. Answer should be obvious after that.

Comment: You may also be reading the $2n!$ in the numerator as $(2n)!$ when it should be $2(n!)$

Comment: Yes. My mistake. Thanks for the help. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numerator should be 2(n+1)!

So you have:

$\frac{2(n+1)!}{n(n+1)}=\frac{2(n+1)(n)(n-1)!}{n(n+1)}=2(n-1)!$